# Exporting html table data as CSV displays the data in multiple rows but the row text is in same column

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, csv

I am exporting the table data using javascript, and I am able to export data into CSV format. The column data are separated by comma and after each row there is a newline in the file. Now when I open the file in excel all the data of a row are shown in single column. Here is the CSV file that got generated:

```
"This is Column1","Column2"
"R2 C1","R2 C2"
```

I read that, the region settings might have different separator than what we use, but the separator is indeed comma (,). Also, if I import this file in Excel as said in this [link](http://feedback.debitoor.com/knowledgebase/articles/248576-when-opening-csv-file-all-data-appears-in-one-col) it works. The code with jQuery, from jfiddle, seems to working fine and that also generates same text file, but it opens properly. Below are the two codes,
Using the below code works correct (opens csv with proper columns)
http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/KPEGU/
Using javascript as modified by me (does not work as expected, no columns displayed as said above)
http://jsfiddle.net/KPEGU/1850/
EDIT: The reason is that, endoing is set to **USC-2 Little endian**, so when I change it to Encode in **UTF-8**, the file opens properly. Any hints on how to acheive this endoing? I have tried win.charset='UTF-8'

Comment: To get those CSVs open with Excel per Doubleclick or File-Open, the list separator has to be comma but the decimal separator then cannot also be comma.

Comment: So what is the alternative? and why is the one with jQuery opening properly??

Comment: Both examples have nothing to do with each other. The first works *not* in IE. The second works *only* in IE. The problem with the second is, that `document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"data.csv")` takes not care of the charset. It will ever save as Unicode (16 bit). I  don't know how to avoid this.

Comment: Yes that is the problem! If I change the encoding it'll open properly!